# JQuery Ajax success function being called after beforeSend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blockui

I have the following javascript:

```
function someFunction(string) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "some_endpoint_returning_json",
        async: false,
        data: "param=" + string,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="static/busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
        },
        complete: function () {
            $.unblockUI();
         },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            window.alert(data.status);
        }
    });
}
```

I want the UI to block with the included message before sending the ajax request, then remove the message, unblock the ui and then perform the success function.

Currently here is what is happening:

1. the UI blocks, but doesn't display the message
2. The success window alert pops up
3. Upon confirming the alert window, the BlockUI message pops up for a split second, then the UI unblocks and the page returns to its initial state

Comment: Why are you setting `async` to `false`?  That's the main cause of your problems

Comment: To debug, Can you delay the execution of the server code by few seconds. It could be because before the browser refresh action has happened the ajax request was returned from the server

Comment: it was because async was set to false.  Thank you all for the quick responses.  I'm not a UI guy, I just play one on tv.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set `async` to `false`, the browser will halt the execution of everything while the ajax request is served.  Although `beforeSend` does execute before the ajax request is sent, the synchronous request may occur so quickly that the browser doesn't actually refresh the screen and show your `$.blockUI` changes.  You do get to see them for a very short time after the ajax completes (when they are removed immediately).

If you *must* use async, you may be able to get around this by calling `$.blockUI` separately and setting a short timeout (100 MS perhaps) before starting the ajax request.